# prevent sign in with google if user already signed up with email and password

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire

I am using Angular with Firebase authentication with two authentication options:

- With Email and Password
- With Google

By default in firebase, if you `sign up with email and password`, a new user get created in the authentication users list.

```
this.afAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
```

[image: Sign up with email and password]

If you then `sign in with gmail` using same email, firebase changes the provider to Google.

```
this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(provider)
```

[image: Sign in with google]

By doing this, the user of this email won't be able anymore to `sign in using email and password` option, since he `signed in with google`.

Is there a way to prevent `sign in with google` if the user already `signed up with email and password` option? Maybe by sending a specific parameter when calling `signInWithPopup` firebase method, or by setting a parameter to the `GoogleAuthProvider`.

There is an option in firebase that allows multiple accounts per email but I don't want to use this option.

[image: multiple accounts per email]

Comment: Wouldn't you rather link the accounts so the user can choose either provider?  https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking

Comment: @DougStevenson by doing this if a user sign up with email and password, I will need to force him to link with gmail using popup, so he can use both options in future (so I can guarantee that he can still sign in with email/password if he signs in with gmail). But why should I force this linking if he wants to sign in only using email and password in future? Isn't it possible to reject a sign in with google, if the email is signed up with email provider?

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, this is not possible with the pre-built Firebase Auth UI, but you can do something like what you want via a custom login flow.

Each of the login providers is available as a separate method, as is logging in with email and password. So you can have a login with Google button that only triggers the login with Google popup, and another sign in with email button that signs in with email directly, and requires an email address to be entered into an input somewhere.

Now, if a user ends up using both, the accounts will be linked, but in this case it's not a bad thing, because the user still has the option of whether they want to sign in with Google or sign in via email. and if they choose one on one day and one on the other day, or on different devices different methods, it's not a different account, which would be confusing.

Re: your comment to Doug,

> Isn't it possible to reject a sign in with google, if the email is signed up with email provider?

You *could* do that, though again, not through the prebuilt UI, but I think that behavior would be pretty confusing to the user if they intentionally clicked the sign in with Google button.

Keep in mind that a disadvantage of not using the The prebuilt UI is that you need to handle yourself issues like password resets also.

Answer (score 0):

I have one solution, but force user to login first with email/password.

You have to :

```
const googleAuthProvider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
auth().currentUser.linkWithPopup(googleAuthProvider)
```

After that, u can auth with both.
PS: Do not forget to disable option multiple accounts per email on sign-in methods.
I'm doing this with React and I have the same problem as you mentioned.
If somebody has the right answer,please let us know.